# Why aren't "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security/Connection security rules" and netsh in sync?

Tags: ipsec, windows-firewall, windows, netsh

The screenshot pretty much says it all:

[consec http://uppix.net/7/3/4/eeb1c6e949b90932ca3bd8bfbda47.png](http://uppix.net/7/3/4/eeb1c6e949b90932ca3bd8bfbda47.png)

I don't understand. If I create rules in the MMC snap-in, they don't appear in netsh, if I create rules in netsh, they don't appear in the MMC snap-in. What am I missing here?

(Note: this is Windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out.

My mistake is that I was using the Local Security Policy console to modify the firewall settings. A more direct approach is to use the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" console (in the administration tools). There I can manage rules and they appear in netsh (and vice-versa).